# How do I use batchWriteItem with Node.js to query AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS and I'm having problems trying to develop a simple Lambda function with Node.js. In DynamoDB, I have a table named `Game` with 3 attributes: `gamepk`, `user`, `result`.
In just one single execution of the Lambda function, I want to insert a collection of `game` elements (the number of elements in the collection could vary).
I had been reading some tutorials and it said I should use `batchWriteItem`, but because the collection of Game elements is variable I don't know how to proceed.

Could somebody write a function in Node.js that solves my problem?

An example of the JSON that the lambda function receives is this one:

```json
    {
        "games": [{
                "gamepk": "1",
                "user": "rolo",
                "result": "1-0"

            },
            {
                "gamepk": "2",
                "user": "jhon",
                "result": "1-1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should get you what you need.

1. Create a New Lambda Function
2. Select Node Version 6
3. Select a Role or Create a New one that has DynamoDB Access to Write!
4. Open Created Function in the Web Console
5. Paste the Snippet Bellow into the Cloud 9 Editor

   ```
   const AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');

   exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   // The event parameter is the input to your lambda function
   console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
   let lambdaInput = event['PROPERTY_NAME_DEFINED_IN_POST'];
   let games = [];
   let documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

   lambda.forEach(item => {
     games.push({
       PutRequest: {
         Item: {
           gamepk: item['gamepk'],
           user: item['user'],
           result: item['result']
         }
       }
     });
   });

   let params = {
       RequestItems: {
           'TABLE_NAME': games
       }
   };

   documentClient.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           callback(err);
       } else {
           callback(null, data);
       }
   });
   }
   ```

Save the Function and then you are going to want to select the drop down at the top that says 'Select a Test Event' and then select 'Configure Test Events'.

This will open a new dialog, just save the JSON that is in the main text area and give the test a Name and Save it.

Now select that test that you just made from the 'Select a Test Event' drop down and then click 'Test' in the top right.

This documentation could be found at [AWS Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it worked!.
But theres a thing that im not urdestanding, and maybe I dont explained very well in my question (my english is not good). The lambda function is "activated" by an api-gateway, when someone want to insert something in table "Game" it sends a POST with the collection in a JSON. Seeing your answers, its like your function only inserts two elements. Could you say me how to modify the function to recieve a collection in JSON and insert all of the elements at the same time?.

Comment: I've updated the lambda function to suit your needs, please mark correct if this works for you.

Answer (score 7):

As an additional help for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852947/3175960) , you can use an environment variable and use it in the following way:

```
const MI_TABLE = process.env.MI_TABLE

  let params = {
      RequestItems: {
           [ MI_TABLE ] : games
      }
  };

return await batchWrite(params);
```